# How to size an electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, magnetic-fields

How can I size an electromagnet? For example if I would to attract a mass of $x$ kg what are the calculations that I must do to size the ferromagnetic core and of course the solenoid? And thus, how can I compute the force of the magnetic field generated?

- Current: AC 230V @ 50Hz.
- Material: Iron.
- Distance: 30 cm.

Comment: There are ambiguities, given that you can trade off e.g. shape and current (oftentimes one sees the cores have tapered ends to produce a locally very strong field). More importantly, you should understand that a mass is not a sufficient goal. Are you trying to attract a permanent magnet? a piece of iron? a piece of aluminum? How far away is it?

Comment: @ChrisWhite Please, see my update question... Do you need more informations?